# DDD Events Between Aggregates Example

Tags: events, aggregate, domain-driven-design, domain-events

I have two aggregates

item and price adjustment.

A price adjustment will contain an item adjustment which will say, for a specific item, raise it by x percent (e.g. 10%)

my item has a list price which is what needs to be updated/adjusted.

so when the price adjustment is processed, it is going to find that item and needs to adjust that item's list price by the percentage specific. When the adjustment is complete, the item adjustment in the price adjustment needs to be marked as complete

My question is how is this updating of the list price and marking of the item adjustment being performed composed into events?

What is the correct way for me to both update the list price and mark the item adjustment as completed following events?

Is this a correct solution?:

- call function on the item such as AdjustListPrice and pass in the price adjustment information such as the id and percentage to be adjusted by.
- Then raise an event such as ItemListPriceAdjusted have the price adjustment listen so that it can mark the adjustment as complete and raise another event such as itemPriceadjustmentCompleted

if this is the correct way, should the new calculated list price be added to the ItemListPriceAdjusted price, or should just the adjustment percentage be added and this is then calculated when it is applied/read from the aggregate?

Thanks

Edit:

The option i currently went with is when the price adjustment is being processed, it will go through each of the item adjustments.

It will find the item that it targets and call the function
AdjustPrice(Guid priceAdjustmentId, decimal adjustmentPercentage)

This will calculate the new list price for that item and the item will emit an ItemPriceAdjusted event, which contains the price adjustment id, the and the new list price

The price adjustment will then listen for these events and mark the relevant item adjustment as complete, in turn emitting its own ItemAdjustmentCompleted Event

Answer (score 1):

We are talking DDD here. So the first question I'd ask is what's happening in the business that you want to reflect with code.

It is highly unlikely that a business would decide to "adjust prices" by 10% on the whole assortment. That has something to deal with the pricing strategy. Which is individual to a product or a category of products. So, I'd start with asking the business first.

Next, if in the underlying business you have some dedicated people or departments to deal with the pricing, that would give you the context boundary. Most likely pricing is a separate domain from inventory (listing the products). Most likely there is some base price, the prime cost of a product. Then there are some additional costs, some margin to it which will form the profit. So, by "adjusting" a price - what are you going to achieve? Does it mean that a prime cost changed? Or a margin changed? Or some marketing campaign ended? Figure it out - and you'll get the answer to your question. You'll be able to derive the event name from it.

To sum up: store/fire/raise/dispatch an event that is relevant to THE business.

Comment: I purposely left out a bit of detail, but i will explain a bit.
In our business we want to adjust a selected group of items or client items. Without getting too in depth, our pricing adjustment aggregate, has a list of item adjustment and client adjustments.
This is essentially how we determine what we need to adjust (which items and item ajdustments)
Now we see all of this being in the "catalogue" bounded context atm, because its to do with the price we list for our customers (just to throw that in, so you know there inst multiple boundaries)

Comment: The price adjustment will be confirmed and we then will figure out what items and client items need to be adjusted
so we end up with a list of item adjustments and client adjustments under the price adjustment. They are under the price adjustment because we also care that when all adjustments have been complete, then the price adjustment can be marked as complete aswell.
the adjustments also denote the adjsutment price that item will be increased by.
But a key thing is to track when it has been done.

Comment: So we also have an aggregate for item and client item, which is where the list price is held.
So currently what I have is, when you process the price adjustment, you are going to go down each of those item adjustments, find the specific item and call adjust price on it. (i went with that way) that raises the event ItemPriceAdjustedEvent, which hold a reference to the price adjustment.
I also put this on the item because you can change the price normally through it.
This process also occurs for client items

Comment: My real question is i think, if i adjust the price on the item aggregate, it will adjust the price of it and raise an event. I can pick that event up on my price adjustment and then mark my item adjustment as being completed.
That seems fine, as it keeps the concerns related to them and ensures the transaction of the price adjustment status and item price being consistent.
However, we havent got transactional consiustency between the adjustment being done and marked as complete. It is eventual. Is this fine? I mean in the real world it might be ok?

Comment: 1. Real world works exactly eventually consistently. That should be ok to show the previous price until an item "knows" an adjusted price. You can aim to reduce this "acknowledge gap" to a minimum by the means of technology, but from the business perspective that should be completely Ok.

Comment: 2. If consistency is mandatory - then an event should be a transaction. It also means that a consistency boundary should not span two different aggregates. You have a design decision to make. Whether there are two eventually consistent aggregates or there is one immediately consistent.

I'd lean towards less numerous, more complex and more long-living aggregates instead of a larger number of shorter-lived ones. Imagine a hospital patient's record book. There is a single aggregate per patient (physical record book), not per doctor visit. Or there is one metric book per church, not per person.

Comment: The item has to work out the adjustment price when given a percentage to adjust by. 
I have updated the question with a better description of my current implementation

Comment: Cyclical dependency between Item and PriceAdjustment looks bad. They listen to each other's events. Since the decision to adjust a price in PriceAdjustment is made up, it can be the responsibility of some third piece of logic to execute this decision: call AdjustPrice on an item, ensure that it was a success, then update status of the PriceAdjustment.

Comment: But we are talking about two separate transactions here. An edge case is when only one of them succeeds. It should be retried in case of a technical issue. Or a human should deal with it otherwise. Then a human should learn about the issue somehow.